# ckeditor - лишние знаки слеш. (\\)

Tags: php, ckeditor, mysql

Добрый день, ув. Специалисты. Скажите, пожалуйста, чем может быть вызвана следующая проблема с `ckeditor`:

```
<p>
<a href=\"http://ruslandscape.ru/images/pic1.jpg\">http://ruslandscape.ru/images/pic1.jpg</a></p>
<p>
<img alt=\"xczczcz\" src=\"http://ruslandscape.ru/images/pic1.jpg\" style=\"width: 308px; height: 257px; \" /></p>
```

В общем, суть проблемы заключается в том, что `CKeditor` вставляет **** в ссылки и картинки. И в таком не правильном виде информация попадает в БД, а далее и на сайт, где в результате не отображаются картинки и не срабатывают ссылки.
Самое забавное, что у меня на ПК этот глюк удалось как то вывести, обновлением `ckeditor-а`, а вот при загрузке сайта на сервер - все равно этот глюк остается. Ума не приложу что делать, посоветуйте, если кто-знает в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Скорее всего из-за автоматического экранирования кавычек такое
Вот почитайте http://php.su/security/?magicquotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А у вас, когда в БД заносится значение, оно экранируется? mysql_real_escape_string то есть.

Comment: да, данная экранировка используется, я счел ее оптимальной. Так вот интересно что с ее учетом, у меня на денвере все работает, а на интернет сервере нет. Собственно из-за этой разницы и возник мой вопрос, я считаю нельзя отменять данный экран, даже не смотря на то, что данный способ введения тексты будет доступен только администратору сайта. Вот и ищу обходной путь.
Собственно этот экран у меня применяется везде, тоесть у меня на сайте выводится несколько типов контента, но слеши вылазят только в блоке с основным текстом и изображениями. Вот у меня и возник вопрос почему он тут блокирует.

Comment: вы так и не сказали  - включен ли magic_quotes_gpc на хосте

Comment: Каким бы глупым решением это ни было, но когда я столкнулся с этой проблемой я убрал mysql_real_escape_string для строки, обрабатываемой ckeditor. Возможно она где-то до этого уже экранировалась, но я не стал разбираться в этом, проблем пока при добавлении в базу не было обнаружено, какие бы символы я не использовал.

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает убрать слэши?

```
$str = stripslashes($str); /*Удаляем обратные слэши*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем в  файл `php.ini` строчку:

```
magic_quotes_gpc=off
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот редактор всегда экранирует. В интернете есть много информации по борьбе с этим. В крайнем случае, можете самостоятельно это отключить и поправить(но лучше это делать есть кроме вас им точно никто не будет пользоваться или точно не будут  пытаться что-то сделать по книге, возомнив себя хакером))) Файл называете fceditor-php5.php или как-то так. К сожалению нет под рукой, с телефона пишу.

Comment: а можно чуть чуть подробнее, я уже был в этом файле сегодня. Пробовал его редактировать, но что-то изменений не увидел, заранее большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, у Вас из базы же вывод идет? 
я обычно делаю так

```
$s=mysql_query("select * from table where text!=(либо <>)"" (либо is not null) ");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($s);
if ($s)
{
    echo '<div>'.str_replace('\"', '"', $r["text"]).'</div>';
}
```

}